# Is there any library functions in C to check the Internet connection?

Tags: c, linux, internet-connection

Can you give me a simplest method to check the Internet availability using a C program in Linux?

I have implemented a program to run the system command 'traceroute' in C. Before this I have to check whether the Internet connection is available or not. So can you suggest a method?

Comment: "Doesn't work well" is like taking long coffee breaks or what?

Comment: Is there any library functions? (I'm new to network programming)

Comment: Well, there is a big problem - the internet does not exist as one entity, so you cannot 100% reliably detect any 'connection ' to it.  You can guess with some certainty - if you ping Google and it fails,.you have no internet connection..or Google is unreachable for some reason at that time.....

Comment: 'Before this I have to check whether the Internet connection is available or not' - why?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit : Thank you. Now I understand what's the path I have to follow. I'm trying with pinging google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  no.  Neither C nor C++ has direct knowledge of networking, or any built-in networking functions.

Depending on what 3rd-party libraries you are using, there may be something you can use, but that depends on the library, it isn't directly part of C.

I can imagine there are libraries out there that might try to ping some internal/external address, perform a name lookup, etc.  But if you're on an isolated network, not having the ability to ping, lookup, or cross a firewall to get to a certain location may be perfectly valid, and doesn't indicate a networking problem.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest me a method to check the Internet availability? I'm asking about a simple c function or something like that..

Comment: "Simple"?  No.  Depends on what is needed, and the network.  Do you need to check connectivity to a server?  Check if the name server is up?  Check if the firewall is letting TCP or UDP packets through?  Check if a port is open?  There is no "simple" solution to this question.

Comment: Ok. I'm just running the 'traceroute' command using a C program. So, I have to check the Internet connection before run the system command. That's my problem. Please can you suggest a method to do this.

Comment: 'So, I have to check the Internet connection before run the system command' - why?  Run it anyway.  If it fails, deal with it.